# Multiple simultaneous VPN connections

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, openvpn, routing-table

I am using terminal to connect to multiple VPN instances (in parallel, from a single terminal) with openvpn api in Go. I have many VPN servers. Some combinations of VPNs work together but some of other don't. Those connections get interrupted and from that moment i lose access to internet at all. I suspect there will be some collision between routes or DNS get messed up or some deadlock happens. After ping-restart the connection gets fixed for a moment until it tries to reconnect again gets into the loop.

Anyone with experience knows what might possibly happen here and how to fix it. I am not that good in networking so please let me know if additional info is required.

Comment: This question does not provide enough information to go on.  A common issue you might be having is that some VPN instances may have shared/overlapping IP address ranges which is problematic, and does not have an easy global solution.  It is also possible some VPN servers are publishing default routes which may conflict with others.

Comment: @davidgo, thanks for the comment, these kind of hints were what i was exactly looking. Some clue where to find the issue. thanks a lot. If you can tell me a little bit more what tools i have to use and how to understand what is the real problem, that would be perfect

Comment: I have 3 vpns which work together perfectly although i can see that they add same routes with different gateway addresses. so multiple colliding routes does not seem to be a problem